# How to present different UI on first vs subsequent app use?

Tags: android, user-interface, sharedpreferences

I have a simple android page with a spinner, two check boxes and a submit button. The java code for the screen is as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button submit;
    private Button edit;

    Spinner place;
    private CheckBox male;
    private CheckBox female;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);

        edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        place = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.place);
        place.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                       int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                str_specimen = item;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        male = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.male);
        male.setChecked(false);
        female = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.female);
        female.setChecked(false);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,
                        home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have a edit button that is not visible initially. When I choose a value from spinner and check a value in the check box and click on submit button. These values are sent to database and `home` page will launch.

What I want to do is that, when I visit the main page again, I want the previously selected values to appear and the spinner and checkbox should not be clickable, and the edit button should show up. If i click on the edit button the spinner and checkbox should be clickable and i should be able to submit again.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You can use SharedPreference for this purpose .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a method, say isFirstVisit(), that returns a boolean if this is the first time the user is on that activity:

```
private boolean isFirstVisit() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getBoolean("IsFirstVisit", true);
}
```

Call it before you start adjusting your UI and then based on its value show/hide/check/uncheck/enable/disable various UI elements:

```
boolean firstTime = isFirstVisit();

edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
if(firstTime) {        
    edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Don't forget to set `IsFirstVisit` to `false` when done:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
ed.putBoolean("IsFirstVisit", false);
ed.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` after click

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("place", place.getSelectedItem().toString(););
 editor.putInt("male", male.getText());
 editor.putInt("female", female.getText());
 editor.commit();
```

Retrieve data from preference after `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String place = prefs.getString("place" null);
  String male = prefs.getString("male", null);  
  String female = prefs.getString("female", null); 
}
```